# How to prevent ie from decoding a utf-8 url in flash?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, utf-8, http-status-code-301

I'm finding that in flash (10.x at least) and ie (7, 8, 9) that if I try to load an image url that contains escaped utf-8 characters (p%C3%83%C2%A5) that the characters get decoded before it makes the url request, even if I double or triple encode them.  Is there any way to prevent this so the url (with escapes) the way I want it is actually what is requested?

The problem its causing is we give a http status of 301 on utf-8 decoded url requests to the encoded url which flash then tries to request (but ie decodes it again) and I get stuck in an infinite loop because of the 301 + ie auto-decoding.

EDIT, adding code sample:

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://mydomain.com/p%C3%A5.jpg');
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(url);
```

Now I want the request to go over the line as http://mydomain.com/p%C3%A5.jpg (and it does in other browsers), but in IE it goes over the line as http://mydomain.com/pÃ¥.jpg

EDIT: I also tried the (good) suggestion of replacing % with %25 (double encoding the %) but that didn't work, it just caused this request to go over the wire:

http://mydomain.com/p%25C3%25A5.jpg

Comment: It sounds like you are misusing urlencoding. Post the flash code that makes the request

Comment: IE isn't only decoding the URL, it's most likely decoding it erroneously. It's using the Windows default encoding (ish), when it probably should be UTF-8. This could be because the page itself isn't set to use UTF-8 maybe.

Comment: It looks like its decoding it correctly, the request over the wire is the decoded url, I just wish it would send the unencoded url as I specify it should.

Comment: I take it back, bzlm you're right, those characters are incorrectly encoded, that actually wound up being part of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is probably trying to resolve the file name by decoding it first.

301 is a redirect
Why not just make a redirct page
This could be another option for you.

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://mydomain.com/redirpage.php?page=p%C3%A5.jpg');
```

Comment: IE is certainly trying to resolve the filename by decoding it first which seems kinda lame since I'm telling it exactly how I want the url requested and its changing it.  The redirect page is a solution but that would mess up our CDN caching since the request url would be different than what the CDN has cached.

Comment: In your server script populate the location with the value of the parameter passed "page=" refer to the following link on how to set up the redirect page. http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php